# preg_match, addslashes,mb_substr not working for long strings

Tags: php, preg-match, multiline, addslashes

I am parsing an html file. I have a big string which is basically a script.
The string looks likes this:

> var spConfig = new
>   Product.Config({"outofstock":["12663"],"instock":["12654","12655","12656","12657","12658","12659","12660","12661","12662","12664","12665"],"attributes":{"698":{"id":"698","code":"aubade_import_colorcode","label":"Colorcode","options":[{"id":"650","label":"BLUSH","price":"0","products":["12654","12655","12656","12657","12658","12659","12660","12661","12662","12663","12664","12665"]}]},"689":{"id":"689","code":"aubade_import_size_width","label":"Size
>   Width","options":[{"id":"449","label":"85","price":"0","products":["12654","12657","12660","12663"]},{"id":"450","label":"90","price":"0","products":["12655","12658","12661","12664"]},{"id":"451","label":"95","price":"0","products":["12656","12659","12662","12665"]}]},"702":{"id":"702","code":"aubade_import_size_cup","label":"Size
>   Cup","options":[{"id":"1501","label":"A","price":"0","products":["12654","12655","12656"]},{"id":"1502","label":"B","price":"0","products":["12657","12658","12659"]},{"id":"1503","label":"C","price":"0","products":["12660","12661","12662"]},{"id":"1504","label":"D","price":"0","products":["12663","12664","12665"]}]}},"template":"\u20ac#{price}","basePrice":"57","oldPrice":"57","productId":"12666","chooseText":"Choose
>   option...","taxConfig":{"includeTax":true,"showIncludeTax":true,"showBothPrices":false,"defaultTax":19.6,"currentTax":19.6,"inclTaxTitle":"Incl.
>   Tax"}});
>           var colorarray = new Array();
>
> ```
>               colorarray["c650"] = 'blush';
>
>     Event.observe('attribute698', 'change', function() {
>
>       var colorId = $('attribute698').value;
>       var attribute = 'attribute698';
>       var label = colorarray["c"+colorId];
>
>       if ($('attribute698').value != '') {
>           setImages(attribute, colorId, label);
>         }
>     }); //        var currentColorLabel = 'blush'; //        var currentSku = '5010-4-n'; //        var currentPosition = 'v'; // //
> ```
>
> Event.observe(window, 'load', function() { //
>     setImages('attribute698', null, currentColorLabel); //        });

I need to extract the content from first "(" upto first ";".
I have tried to do string extract and failed.I have tried preg match I have failed.
Kindly tell me some solution to my problem.Below are my tried solution and issues.

```
$strScript =  $tagscript->item(0)->nodeValue;
//this line returns empty string
$str_slashed = addslashes(trim($strScript) );   
$pattern = '/\((.*);/';
preg_match($pattern,$str_slashed,$matches);
echo 'matches'."<br />";
var_dump($matches);

//Add slashes works only if I use it before assignment to other string
$matches = array();
$strScript = addslashes ($tagscript->item(0)->nodeValue);//. "<br />";
$pattern = '/\((.*);/';
preg_match($pattern,$strScript,$matches);
echo 'matches'."<br />";
var_dump($matches);

//str extract method
$posBracket = stripos ($strScript,'(');
 echo $posBracket."<br />";
$posSemiColon = strpos ($strScript,';');
 echo $posSemiColon."<br />";
$temp = mb_substr ($strScript,$posBracket ,($posSemiColon-$posBracket));
echo $temp."<br />";
```

The above code works for small strings

```
$strScript = "manisha( [is goo girl] {come(will miss u) \and \"play} ; lets go home;";
```

but wont work for the long strings.
How can i resolve this issue?Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

You have to add multiline switch to your regular expressions.
Try `$pattern = '/\((.*);/s';` or `$pattern = '/\((.*);/m';`

Comment: I checked with /m and /s option on small string with new line I am getting output.but not on the string which i need. Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Try using `/\(([^;]*)/` as your pattern. `[^;]` means any character that is not a `;`.

Edit: also turn multiline mode on, as suggested by [rogers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/501894/rogers); therefore the whole pattern should look somewhat like  `/\(([^;]*)/s`.

Edit: you should be aware, that this is not really error-proof. Say, you'll get a `;` inside some property of the object of which JSON representation is included in your string.

Comment: The pattern you suggested also does not give me results.

Comment: Yes.I need that json string to work.Thats the whole purpose of my str extract.